# Проблема с записью в массив JAVA

Tags: java, массивы

Создал цикл для записи в массив строк, введенных с консоли. Возникли трудности. При запуске цикла пропускается первая итерация и сразу же переходит ко второй.

```
        int quantity;   // количество choose
        System.out.println("Enter quantity options");
        quantity = in.nextInt();
        String options[] = new String[quantity];  //created array with length = quantity
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter your " + (i+1) + " option");
            options[i] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Это то, что она выводит

```
Enter quantity options
3
Enter your 1 option
0
Enter your 2 option
Second
1
Enter your 3 option
3
```

Как видно после "Enter your 1 option" от меня не требуют ввода во время первой итерации цикла - вот в чем проблема.

Я новичок в JAVA, поэтому туплю)

Comment: А в чём этот "выбор" состоит?

Comment: Я имел ввиду "Ввод", прошу прощения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt` не считывает конец строки

```
quantity = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
...
```

Comment: Спасибо  большое. Странное, конечно, свойство у next.Int()

Comment: @ArtOwl Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.